# get html control value in MVC3 control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
<select id="showOption">
            <option id="1" >All Friends</option>
            <option id="2">Friends who like it</option>
            <option id="3">Friends who don't like it yet</option>
        </select>
```

when there is a post of the form that contains the html above, how can I get the selected value in the controller.
Shouldn't the code look like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id, string showOption)
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set attribute `name` on the `select` element. Also it looks like you don't want `id` attribute on `option` element, but `value` attribute.

```
<select id="showOption" name="showOption">
    <option id="1">All Friends</option>
    <option id="2">Friends who like it</option>
    <option id="3">Friends who don't like it yet</option>
</select>
```